# Two functions that subscribe to the server api, executed in sequence

Tags: angular

I have a question - it may seem obvious to you, but I can't figure it out.

`getCategoryID()` and `getRecipeList()`

The first one gets from the API a list of the `category` array, the second function uses this list to send (n = array length) requests regarding the `recipes`.

At the end, I want a array: category name + recipe name

The problem is that both use subscribe. Due to the fact that they are asynchronous, functions execute too quickly. Tried using `await` - but then it returns me a `Promise`. I want the first function to wait for the api to api query and pass the data to the second, not the promise

```
getCategoriesFromAPI() {
    this.apiService.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

```
getRecipesFromAPI() {
    this.apiService.getRecipes(categoryID).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you could use mergeMap https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap for this. Somehting along the lines of getCagegoriesFromAPI().pipe(mergeMap( do requests need here and return them ). you can think of it in the simplest terms as if its a .then on an promise for observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out RXJS pipes. They help you with working with different observables. In your case I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
this.apiService.getCategories().pipe(
  switchMap((categories) => forkJoin(
    categories.map((category) => this.apiService.getRecipes(category.id))
  ))
).subscribe((recipes) => {
  // This should return array of arrays [[recipe, recipe, recipe], [recipe, recipe]]
  console.log(recipes);
})
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: Is there a way to combine two arrays and have this structure? { categoryName: FirstCategory, recipes : recipe1, recipe2, recipe3} not necessarily json - but a combination of arrays of categories and recipes